# Getting an error when running the basic Express project

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm messing around with Node.js for the first time and decided to create a simple application using express.  I followed the instructions from [github](https://github.com/visionmedia/express) in an empty directory like so:

```
npm install -g express
express
npm install -d
node app.js
```

When navigating to `localhost:3000` I get the follow error:

```
Express
500 Error: Cannot find module './lib/jade'
at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:332:11)
at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
at require (module.js:370:17)
at Object. (C:\dev\gravity_kata\node_modules\jade\index.js:4:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
```

When looking under `node_modules\jade\lib` I see all of Jade's library files, but no `jade` folder.  So I created a folder under lib called jade and moved the library files there and now my default application works.

Now, seeing as I have nearly no experience with Node.js and Express I'm pretty sure I did something wrong.  Does anybody have any idea what is going on here?

**Edit:**

I dove into the Jade code.  Under Jade's index.js file it requires `lib\jade` and looking under the lib folder, there was no `jade.js` file.  Well, that is the problem, but why is the jade.js file missing?  When pulling the Jade [source](http://search.npmjs.org/#/jade) from npm, there is a jade.js file under the lib directory.  I copied the lib folder from the downloaded source into the Jade module for my project and it works fine now.

So for some reason, npm isn't pulling down the jade.js file.  The version in the `packages.json` file match the source i pulled down, `0.21.0`.  Anybody have an idea on why this happened?

Comment: Seems like that it's a jade or express issue. Try to dive into the code...

Comment: I edited my response on what I found after digging into the code.

Comment: Downloading from source and extracting worked for me. Thanks for pointing out the missing file. Must be a bug with NPM/Jade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, on windows, jade version 0.22.0 fixed the issue.

Comment: It must have been a bug in jade, because version 0.22.0 fixed the issue for me as well.

Answer (score 11):

cd to your express project folder and run "npm install", this will install all dependencies

Comment: When you say express project folder, do you mean the `/node_modules/express` directory?

Comment: are you running linux or windows?

lets say you create a project on your desktop using

express testproject

then 

cd testproject

npm install

Comment: im sorry im not good with comments , i will re write that comment

Comment: first create a project by typing express testproject .... after that type cd testproject .... and after that type npm install

Comment: I'm running on windows.  Ok, you meant my projects directory, not the directory of the installed express module.  I did run `npm install` with the `-d` option.  I was just a little confused since in my original question I specified I did that.  So, needless to say, running `npm install` did not fix the error.

Comment: sorry i did not see that line

Answer (score 2):

it probably has to do with the fact, that you installed express globally (`-g`), but the `npm install -d` was done locally. try to install them both globally, or as i would prefer, both locally:

```
sudo npm uninstall express -g
npm install express
npm install jade (or npm install -d)
```

Comment: Installing express globally gives access to the executable.  I removed express globally, but express and jade were already installed locally.  I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Really make sure that all the module `require`s are correct. Javascript is very funny about telling you what is actually wrong. Try removing the jade template line and see what happens then.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this problem with the error of jade module. Looks like the jade folder was doesn't created automaticly (some kind of bug). Now i resolved this with reinstall jade. After that the jade folder was automaticly created.
use *npm uninstall gulp-jade* and then install gulp-jade again